# Passing session to function in Gatling Java

Tags: java, scala, session, gatling

I am trying to pass the session to a function in Gatling as shown in .body():

```
                    exec(http("ED/CTS/SGM")
                                .post(IDS_BASE_URL + edEndpoint)
                                .body(StringBody(createBodyStringForStudentAssignmentSetup(session)))
                                .headers(getHeaderMap)
                                .check(status().is(201),
                                        jsonPath("$.assignments[0].refId").saveAs("assignmentRefId")));
```

The function being called is shown here:

```
public class CreateAssignmentDataSetup {

    public static Body.WithString createBodyStringForStudentAssignmentSetup(Session session)
    {

        
        String title;

        String assignmentName = "PerformanceTest_AssignmentApi_";

        title = assignmentName.concat(LocalDate.now().toString());
        
        String studentsList = session.getString("listOfStudents");


.... 
....

       return StringBody(body);
 
    }
```

Is it possible to pass "session" values like this to "createBodyStringForStudentAssignmetnSetup()" like this, since using an exec(session-> block (shown below) will not allow requests to be triggered for some reason:

```
exec(session -> {

});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`StringBody` takes a Function<Session, String> so you want to write:

```java
    public static String createBodyStringForStudentAssignmentSetup(Session session)
    {

        
        String title;

        String assignmentName = "PerformanceTest_AssignmentApi_";

        title = assignmentName.concat(LocalDate.now().toString());
        
        String studentsList = session.getString("listOfStudents");


.... 
....

       return body;
    }

       
.body(StringBody(CreateAssignmentDataSetup::createBodyStringForStudentAssignmentSetup))
```

Comment: When I use this, the body value is prefixed as "body:StringRequestBody{charset=UTF-8, content={
  "title":
....
...."

Is there an alternative to StringBody here or a way to prevent that prefix being added?

Comment: You're doing something wrong. Note that my "createBodyStringForStudentAssignmentSetup" returns a String. It looks like you're returning StringBody(body).toString(), which is wrong. Return a plain String.

Comment: ` String body = parsedString.replace("\"$studentRefIdList\"", builder.substring(0, builder.toString().length() - 1))
                .replace("$title", title)
                .replace("$teacherRefId", String.valueOf(session.getString("userRefId")))
                .replace("$sectionId", String.valueOf(session.getString("sectionRefId")))
                .replace("$sif_RefObject", String.valueOf(session.getString("assignmentType")))
                .replace("$availableDate", availableDate)
                .replace("$dueDate", dueDate);
        

        return body;`

Comment: That is what is returned as body, sorry about the format.

Comment: Ah, but you're just checking the Gatling logs and assuming `body:StringRequestBody{charset=UTF-8, content={` is what's sent on the wire? It's not. Just the content.

Comment: Ah ok so false alarm so! Thanks again Stéphane.

Comment: 1 last question: 

I seem to get this error:
"Required request body is missing: public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<com.hmhco.assignmentapi.rest.domain.v4.TeacherAssignmentsV4Rest> com.hmhco.assignmentapi.rest.controller.v4.TeacherAssignmentControllerV4.createTeacherAssignment(com.hmhco.assignmentapi.rest.domain.v4.TeacherAssignmentsV4Rest)".

I get the same error when I use postman and make a request without any body value, however the above .body(StringBody(...)) should be passing the String as the body for the request. Do you know why this is the case? Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but there's no way to help you unless you provide a proper reproducer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: "StringBody takes a Function<Session, String>" not anymore? On gatling 3.8.3 at least. I am a java dev, and I've been killing myself on how to add a simple body to a request in that version, can you update this answer please?

Comment: @Eugene no idea what you're doing, but nothing has changed and StringBody still takes a Function<Session, String> in Java, see https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/main/gatling-core-java/src/test/java/io/gatling/javaapi/core/CoreJavaCompileTest.java#L43

Comment: @Eugene I recommend you open your own thread and provide a reproducer as requested above so we can understand what you're doing wrong.

Comment: @StéphaneLANDELLE nvm - I was jus an idiot, really. I was looking for `body(StringBody(...)` and my confusion came from `StringBoby` which is a _method_ call, in java api. Sorry for taking your time.

Comment: No pro :) Indeed, `StringBody` is a static method, not a class name. We want the Java DSL syntax to be close to the Scala DSL one.